# Using zsh, trying make a function to print out only the first n lines of any piped input

Tags: zsh

Here's my function so far:

```
function tinput() {
  let counter=0
  tail -f $1 |{
    while read data; do
      if [ counter -gt ${2:2} ]
      then
        counter=0
      else
        printf "$data"
    counter=counter+1
      fi
    done
  }
}
```

This function is for showing the first n lines of say tail-f output rather then the whole thing, I'm pretty new to bash script (or derivatives thereof).

At the moment It errors with:

```
tinput:4: parse error: condition expected: counter
```

I think it's becuase the `counter` variable I declared is outside of the loops scope and so it doesn't exist, maybe?

Comment: Use `$counter` to refer to the value of variable `counter`.

Comment: Have a look at the 'head' command. Also you have to refer to a variable with $ in front, so after counter=something, use it as $counter. Second line should not use let. "counter=0" is enough. Then the counter=counter+1 part should be "let counter+=1" or "counter=$(( $counter + 1 )).

Comment: If your counter is greater than ${2:2} it resets the counter rendering the entire exercise pointless (well.. I guess it will skip every ${2:2}+1 line from `tail -f` output). How about just `tail -f $1 | head -${2:2}`

Comment: btw, `printf "$data"` is not (the correct alternative) `printf '%s\n' "$data"`. The former changes `\t` into a literal tab, tries to match `%s` or `%d` or whatnot with an argument to print, &c. Even if you **want** `\t`, `\n`, `\f`, etc. to be honored as escapes rather than literal strings, that would be `printf '%b\n' "$data"`.

Comment: @ JNevill, that would be becuase I haven't gotten around to making it stop outputting when it' gets to that point. @ Charles Duffy that's good to know. @ Miko, see comment in other answer,

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `repeat` command.

```
function tinput() {
  tail -f $1 | repeat ${2:-2} IFS= read -re
}
```

---

Some explanations:

1. This is the short form of the `repeat` loop, since there is only a single command in the body. (The long form would look like

   ```
   repeat ${2:-2} do
     IFS= read -re
   done
   ```

or `repeat ${2:-2} do IFS= read -re; done`.
)

2. `IFS= read -r` ensures that each line is read verbatim, without trimming any leading or trailing whitespace, or processing any backslash-escaped characters in the input.
3. The `-e` option causes `read` to echo its input back to standard output without assigning the input to a variable.

Comment: I just tried that function and it closes exit's as soon as it runs.

Comment: `${2:2}` was a rather damaging typo for `${2:-2}`; instead of replacing an empty value of `$2` with 2, it expanded to a substring of `$2` starting with the 3rd characters. As a result, any number smaller than 100 out be replaced with an empty string.

Comment: Ok, that worked, thank you VERY much! just an fyi, this is for reading out server error logs, but I only need like, the top 3 lines, at most to get the error and the line it's on from the stack trace. I've tried using standard cli tools but none of them worked correctly (or in the way I needed), hence trying to role my own.

Comment: Ok, I Just started up the webserver and it does the same thing `head` does, the moment the log file grows and `tail -f` outputs it, it exists and goes back to the terminal interface.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me user @JNevill is onto something.  I would suggest using:

```
tail -f $1 | head -${2}
```

where $1 is your file and $2 is the number of lines you want to read from the top.

Comment: Why `tail -f`, if you want to read from the top? Wouldn't that just be `head -$2 <"$1"`?

Comment: Many ways to do it.  I'm just following the OP's code example where the OP is using `tail -f` and OP just wants to replace the `while` loop where the error seems to be located.  But a good point nonetheless.

Comment: becuase `head` doesn't work,  the moment tail -f outputs some value, head just stops, that and I don't want the first n lines of the log files, I want the first n lines of  the output of `tail -f`, I've tried grep, I've tried head and I've tried sed and none of them worked, hence me trying to role my own, plus I thought it would be an interesting learning exercise.